# Simulink: Avoid non-constant expression or empty matrix with structures

Tags: matlab, function, structure, simulink

I want to get some data in the structures 'A' and 'B' which are fields in the structure 'S'. For example:

```
data = S.A.data;
```

The fields "A" and "B" should be accessed in a loop. To access the different named fields I would like to use a second structure "structureNames" in which the names "A" and "B" are specified. The code has to run in a Matlab-Function in Simulink. "S" and "structureNames" are defined as non-tuneable parameter. For example:

```
% Predefined in workspace
structureNames(1).name = 'A'; 
structureNames(2).name = 'B';

% Simulink Matlab-Function
function y = doSomething(S, structureNames)
  for i = 1:size(structureNames,2)
      data = S.(structureNames(i).name).data;
      % Process data and set output y ...
  end
```

Doing this I get the following error message:

> Non-constant expression or empty matrix. This expression must be constant because its value determines the size or class of some expression.

Is there a solution or workaround for this error?

I tried the *fieldnames* function which creates a cell array containing the field names. It worked once but the second time Simulink crashed and I had to restart it. I guess that Simulink doesn't support cells (See [Simulink Supported Data Types](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/data-types-supported-by-simulink.html)).

**Edit**
Images of simulink block and port and data type manager of Matlab-Function. The simulink model contains only this matlab function block.
[image: Simulink Block] [image: Port and data type manager]

I tried the proposed solution with the eval-function. Unfortunately 'eval' is not supported for code generation.

Comment: Any chance you could post how it's connected in Simulink/how the function is called?

Comment: Have you tried using `eval`? Something like `eval(['data = S.',structureNames(i).name,'.data;'])`

Comment: I added two images. I hope it helps to understand the model. As mentioned it is just the matlab-function in the model. No nested subsystems, etc. .

I tried `eval` but it is not supported for code generation.